# File download through JavaScript not initiating browser download

Tags: javascript, laravel, download

The Laravel backend returns a StreamedResponse:

```
return Storage::download($filePath);
```

On the frontend I have the following:

```
async download(patientId, filename) {
    let queryParams = new URLSearchParams();
    queryParams.set('filename', filename);

    await ApiService.get(documentsUrl, queryParams);
}
```

which is called by a VueJS component:

```
<base-card class="document text-center" @click="document.download(file.filename)">
```

The response headers include all values required for the browser to initiate a download:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 95561
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test_file.pdf
```

I have also tried adding an anchor assigning a blob URL and firing a click event, the result is always the same: the HTTP response is successful, with the appropriate headers and the binary in the response but no download.

Comment: An ajax request won't initiate a download. It has to be something that would otherwise reload the page, like an `<a>` tag or a form post.

Comment: ```async download(patientId, filename) {
            let queryParams = new URLSearchParams();
            queryParams.set('filename', filename);

            const response = await ApiService.get(documentsUrl, queryParams);
            const link = document.createElement('a');

            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob());

            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();

            document.body.removeChild(link);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        },```

This isn't working either, same result.

Comment: how about simply `window.location = (your constructed URL)`, no `async` functions or anything like that.

Comment: I need to provide a bearer token for the authentication which is added to the request in ApiService,get().

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that your ApiService.get method is handling the response correctly. Make sure it recognizes and processes the response as a file download. If the backend is returning a stream, your frontend code should be able to handle that.

```
async download(patientId, filename) {
    let queryParams = new URLSearchParams();
    queryParams.set('filename', filename);

    // Ensure that the responseType is set to 'blob'
    const response = await ApiService.get(documentsUrl, queryParams, { responseType: 'blob' });

    // Process the blob response, for example, creating a blob URL and triggering download
    const blob = new Blob([response.data]);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

and Ensure that your backend and frontend are on the same domain or that your backend is configured to handle `cross-origin requests` properly. CORS headers might affect how the browser handles the response.

or Instead of relying on the browser's default behavior, try different approaches like using a library for file downloads or a different method for triggering the download.

For example, you can use the file-saver library:`npm install file-saver`

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

async download(patientId, filename) {
    let queryParams = new URLSearchParams();
    queryParams.set('filename', filename);

    const response = await ApiService.get(documentsUrl, queryParams, { responseType: 'blob' });

    // Use file-saver to trigger the download
    saveAs(response.data, filename);
}
```